# Spring: retrieving JSON data from Python

Tags: python, json, spring-boot

Python:

```
data = {
"id": 1,
"name": "Mike",
"passport":
    {
        "serial": "AM",
        "number": 1234
    }
}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/save-json", data)
```

Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/save-json",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveJson(
        HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Utils.logRequest(request, this.getClass());
    return body;
}
```

Body is: `id=1&passport=serial&passport=number&name=Mike`

requestDumperFilter shows:

```
method=POST
parameter=id=1
parameter=passport=serial, number
parameter=name=Mike
```

Have I missed something? I hope that I made [right](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) json structure.

Comment: Can't edit: this was lost: @RequestBody String body.

Comment: Is your Spring method expecting the posted data to already be in JSON format?

Comment: I guess that something is wrong from the python side. I have 'application/json' header but python sends Post already in a format: id=1&passport=serial&passport=number&name=Mike

Comment: I did a mistake. I've used requests.post(data=data) but had to use requests.post(json=data). It's ok now.